# Node/Express: running specific CPU-instensive tasks in the background

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express, child-process

I have a site that makes the standard data-bound calls, but then also have a few CPU-intensive tasks which are ran a few times per day, mainly by the admin.

These tasks include grabbing data from the db, running a few time-consuming different algorithms, then reuploading the data. What would be the best method for making these calls and having them run without blocking the event loop?

I definitely want to keep the calculations on the server so web workers wouldn't work here. Would a child process be enough here? Or should I have a separate thread running in the background handling all `/api/admin` calls?

Comment: *"Would a child process be enough here"* probably.

Comment: Why dont you kick it off using https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron or https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron-jobs. That way it wont interfere with your http threads.

Comment: I will eventually be moving half of the admin calls to a cron job, but still have half the calls that need to be called manually throughout the day. Would it be fine running a cron job manually and immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer to this scenario in Node.js land is to use the core cluster module - https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html

It is an acceptable API to :

- easily launch worker node.js instances on the same machine (each instance will have its own event loop)
- keep a live communication channel for short messages between instances

this way, any work done in the child instance will not block your master event loop.

Comment: I wanted to set up clustering but since I'm on heroku, they state "... In most cases, clustering more than one worker on a standard-1x dyno will hurt, rather than help performance." I'll give it a go anyways using https://www.npmjs.com/package/forky, since it'll be easy to scale. Thanks.